# Issue QZAP Command and get FIN or IG

Tags: soap, sabre

We are trying to use the QZAP command to clear the queue via the SOAP API as there are no methods avaiable to do that.  However, the response we got from the sysetm is FIN or IG.  Any suggestion?

Comment: This has nothing to do with webservices. You probably retrieved a PNR before trying the QZAP. Please check on the proper steps with Sabre's Product Support helpdesk.

Answer (score 0):

That is the response from Sabre that is returned when you are in a stated session, with a PNR pulled up in the AAA area.

If you are using native Sabre commands, you could try sending a simple "I" before you issue the QZAP command, which should clear the work area you are in.

Comment: Thanks drtrobridge,  that works well.  Just curious, what is the command I for?

Comment: "I" is known as the "ignore" command - it will drop you out of the record without saving any changes.